# return _default_decoder.decode(s) error produced when reading json file in python

Tags: python, json

```
import requests
url = 'https://fantasy.premierleague.com/api/entry/{151515}/'
r = requests.get(url)
print(r.json())
```

I'm new to coding and I've been messing around with APIs and have been having success with other pages on the FPL website but this page is playing up and I was wondering if I was missing something.

Comment: `{151515}` should probably be just `151515`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, you shouldn't have used `{}` in your url address, that's what you're missing.